Iot hub deviceupdate-agent fails postinst on bullseyes (11) armv6l raspberry zero
I am trying to perform device multi-step update from Azure Iot hub. For that I am trying to install deviceupdate-agent on raspbian bullseys (11) armv6l 32bit RPI zero.
I am following:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-ubuntu-agent
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/packages-microsoft-prod.deb > ./packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt install ./packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt install aziot-identity-service
sudo apt-get install deviceupdate-agent
And here I get error from postinst:
Register all reference step handlers...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/deviceupdate-agent.postinst: line 218: 15507 Illegal instruction     $adu_bin_path -l 2 --extension-type updateContentHandler --extension-id "microsoft/apt:1" --register-extension $adu_extensions_sources_dir/$adu_apt_handler_file
dpkg: error processing package deviceupdate-agent (--configure):
installed deviceupdate-agent package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 132
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
deviceupdate-agent
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Can somebody  help with this?

when you are getting above error

I am getting it during sudo apt-get install deviceupdate-agent it seems that it gets in postinst function.
The line that it fails at is: $adu_bin_path -l 2 --extension-type updateContentHandler --extension-id "microsoft/apt:1" --register-extension $adu_extensions_sources_dir/$adu_apt_handler_file
I modified /var/lib/dpkg/info/deviceupdate-agent.postinst to see if paths
/usr/bin/AducIotAgent  # This prints $adu_bin_path
/var/lib/adu/extensions/sources/libmicrosoft_apt_1.so # This prints $adu_extensions_sources_dir/$adu_apt_handler_file
